# Single click on altgr or right control as context menu

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, shortcuts, context-menu

I've got new laptop, but I am dealing with one problem. There is no context menu button.

I use alt-gr or right control often, but I was thinking, I alwas use it with another key, so basically single alt-gr or right control click does nothig.

I would like to ask if there is possibility to map single altgr or right control click as context menu popup.

Please, I need your help guys :)